# Regex to match but not include a word before another word

Tags: regex

I have two specific words in a line say `dog` and `cat`.

And say `dog` appears before `cat`.

How do I make a regex which tells me all the lines containing `dog` and `cat`, but show just the words after `dog` till `cat`, including `cat`, but NOT `dog`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1: Lookbehind**

```
(?<=dog).*?cat
```

Details:

- The `(?<=dog)` lookbehind asserts that what precedes the current position is `dog`
- `.*?` lazily matches all characters up to...
- `cat` matches literal characters

**Option 2: `\K` (PCRE, Perl, Ruby 2+)**

```
dog\K.*?cat
```

The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final

**Option 3: Capture Group (JavaScript and other engines that don't support the other two options)**

```
dog(.*?cat)
```

The parentheses capture what you want to Group 1. You have to retrieve the match from Group 1 in your language.

Comment: I'd been hitting my head over this for quite a while... I had actually found the solution before, (lookbehind i.e. but had forgotten). Also didn't know about the javascript unsupport. Thanks.